# Como obter a ID do dispositivo Android com TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()?

Tags: android

Estou usando esse código para pegar o *ID* do dispositivo *Android*.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Mas agora notei que em alguns casos, a *ID* foi gravada como `null`.

- Não estou certo em obter o *ID* dessa forma?
- Em quais circunstâncias isso retorna nulo?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514163/using-telephony-manager-in-android-to-find-imei-number

Comment: Então.. segundo o link esta certo. É uma maneira de obter o IMEI do celular. Na tabela onde esses inserts foram feitos eu descobri uns 15 casos em que esse valor veio nulo. Agora preciso descobrir em quais casos isso acontece.

Comment: Isso depende um pouco do seu propósito de uso. Sugiro a leitura desse artigo : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html Mas lhe adianto que existe um identificador único gerado no momento da instalação que é registrado nos servidores da Google. Talvez isso lhe atenda. Veja a documentação da API em https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Não estou certo em obter o ID dessa forma?

Não para o fim que pretende. [TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) retorna o  [IMEI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) de um telefone [GSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM) ou o [MEID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_equipment_identifier) ou [ESN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number) de telefones [CDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-division_multiple_access). Nem todos os dispositivos Android são telefones.

> Em quais circuntâncias isso retorna nulo?

Quando o dispositivo não é um telefone.
<sub>[(Como saber se o dispositivo é Smathphone ou Tablet e/ou se é capaz de enviar SMS?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-division_multiple_access)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

O `getDeviceId()` retorna somente valor quando o dispositivo é considerando um telefone.

Se quer obter um identificador "único" do dispositivo você pode 
[usar `Secure.ANDROID_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). Veja um exemplo:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
private String android_id = Secure.getString(
    getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

No entanto, você deve ter cuidado, pois é possível editar a configuração de  fábrica do dispositivo, por exemplo, alterando esse valor.

Em [práticas recomendadas para identificadores exclusivos](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html?hl=pt-br) diz o seguinte:

> 1: Evite o uso de identificadores de hardware. Identificadores de hardware, como o SSAID (código Android) e o IMEI, podem ser evitados
>   na maioria dos casos de uso sem limitar os recursos necessários.