# Como recuperar o IMEI do celular programaticamente?

Tags: java, android

então, estou precisando recuperar o IMEI do celular que estiver utilizando o app, tentei usar alguns métodos antigos, mas sempre recebo o aviso que o método foi deprecado...poderiam me ajudar? Agradecido desde já!

código usado:

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198153/2541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `getDeviceId()` está deprecado, de fato, como aponta a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()), desde a API 26.

No lugar dele, utilize o método [getImei()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei()).

```
final String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();
```

Não esquecendo que a seguinte permissão deve ser adicionada ao `manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Além disso, como a permissão de acesso ao IMEI pode ser negada pelo usuário em tempo de execução, convém você tratar essa possibilidade também (o próprio Android Studio sugere esse tratamento), sob pena de, caso contrário, o sistema lançar uma `SecurityException`:

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {               
        //sua lógica aqui
    }

final String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();
```

Comment: Parou o erro. Mas o app nao abre, poderia me ajudar com a permissão, creio que deve ser esse o motivo..

Comment: @LeonardoGoulart Resposta editada.

Comment: Coloquei permissão e tudo mais, mas continua dando erro... especificamente este: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: Neither user 10082 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

Comment: @LeonardoGoulart, você precisa pedir explicitamente a permissão, então. Dá uma olhada [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091327/how-to-ask-for-user-permissions-in-android-6) link e [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001415/neither-user-10632-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state-e) aqui. Ambos têm o que você precisa para pedir permissões ao usuário.

Comment: Então consegui arrumar o erro, porém, ainda continua sem funcionar... dando esse seguinte erro: "Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport" não sei mais o que fazer, tudo que se resume a TelephonyManager não funciona..

Comment: Você está tentando fazer um teste no emulador ou telefone físico? [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823126/4319922) resposta sugere a instalação de uma biblioteca específica no Android Studio e depois o rebuild do projeto. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: Fazendo nos dois,  porém foco é no telefone físico. Quando eu uso o Telephonymanager todos os textviews do MainActivity desaparecem...eu tenho o Sdk instalado e o google service tbm